# ¿Cómo utilizar todos los componentes de Bootstrap 4 en Angular 7 sin jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, angular7

He leído en mil sitios que **no** se debe utilizar **jQuery** en un proyecto Angular 7. He leído los motivos y entiendo el porque. Ahora bien, después de estar picando un proyecto con Front-End en **Angular 7, ng-bootstrap y PrimeNG** y ver que la documentación, especialmente del segundo, es lamentable, estoy viendo que no voy a acabar en la vida.

Entiendo que con ng-bootstrap puedo utilizar los componentes de ng-bootstrap sin necesidad de jQuery, hasta ahí todo bien. La cuestión es, dado que la librería solo tiene doce componentes **¿cómo puedo usar todos los componentes de Bootstrap 4 sin necesidad de añadir a dependencias jQuery ni Popper?**

En caso de que la única opción sea la de jQuery ¿hay alguna forma de que cause un menor impacto en la aplicación?

Comment: Que componentes necesitas de Bootstrap que no estén en ngBootstrap?

Comment: Te sorprenderá ver que realmente hay pocas cosas que necesites más allá de esos componentes, pero en esos casos es más sencillo añadir la lógica por tí mismo: ocultar y mostrar menús, por ejemplo, o cambiar las clases de ciertos elementos para activarlos o desactivarlos. Al usar ngIf/ngFor y ngClass en las plantillas para elegir qué ver y cómo todo se vuelve hasta más fácil que con jQuery

Comment: Por otro lado, creo la pregunta es demasiado amplia: te recomiendo ir trabajando en tu proyecto y, cuando te atasques, hacer una pregunta concreta del tipo: *¿Cómo puedo hacer X con Bootstrap y Angular?* y te ayudaremos gustosamente

Comment: Tenéis toda la razón. 

Lo que buscaba es que lo pico con Bootstrap 4 (collapse, required por ejemplo) funcionara tal cuál en Angular 7. Lo primero si que se puede suplir con el componente collapse de ng-bootstrap, lo segundo por algún motivo en los formularios de Angular 7 no lo acepta o no he puesto la sintaxis adecuada. 

He hecho la prueba y poco te añade jQuery. Gracias otra vez.